# Naturally occuring wildfires in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was out exploring and I ran into an area where all the trees were burning--the leaves were gone, it was trunk pieces that will never burn up.

Now, I have had a wildfire get out of hand some time ago but I don't think it burned anywhere near this area and there are plenty of unburned trees between my wildfire and this patch.

Do wildfires happen on their own?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11552/can-torches-cause-fire

Comment: @badp:  No.  This was far from home, I had never been there and I wasn't carrying anything except a few plants I had harvested on my trip.

Comment: I didn't put it there as a duplicate link, but as a link to a related question :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As you explored, you triggered a chunk to be created. Minecraft decided to put a lava fall in that chunk. The lava spread on the ground. The trees became close enough to catch fire as a result and the fire quickly spread out...

Comment: This has become more common lately since the change that let you  find lava on the surface with pretty good regularity.

Comment: I sure didn't see any lava but I didn't explore the whole burn zone carefully.  There could have been a lava block hiding on the far size of it.  It certainly wasn't a fall unless it was falling into a cave.

Comment: The (outdated) single player commands mod (SPC) had a command to `extinguish` all fires. This helped me out sometimes before my wooden house burnt up.

Answer (score 4):

Now with the weather, lightnings can hit a tree and start a fire. But it's rare because the rain will extinguish it.