# Why is my floor on fire?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

My room:
[image: The sign says "Warning! Lava Below! Dig down with Extreme Caution!"]

Now occasionally, a random piece of my floor will catch fire for about 10-30 seconds:

[image: I've seen two different pieces do it so far]

I am aware of a lava pit immediately below this room, but I thought stone was supposed to be fire resistant!

This has already almost killed me.  What's going on?

Comment: Is it because of the sign I wonder?

Comment: @Raven: I wondered that too, but *I* caught on fire before I placed the sign.

Comment: I've been burnt before by a lava pool that was diagonally adjacent to a block. Are you aware of a pool existing on the other side of that wall?

Comment: @chands: I'm only aware of lava below.  I don't know if there is lava to the sides.

Comment: @chands That would be because you brushed right up against the south-west corner of the lava block. It shouldn't affect the fact that the ground is setting on fire.

Comment: I love the actual question titles on Gaming.SE. Every time I'm browsing through 'What's Hot' and I see something like 'Why is my floor on fire?', I do a double-take and WTF until I read the small text that indicates that the question is on Gaming.SE.

Comment: @kivetros: Well, I'd be surprised if it weren't. It's *on fire*, of course it's gonna be hot!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Apparently fireballs from lava can [tunnel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling) through up to two blocks sometimes causing a considered-to-be-safe location to catch fire.

<sup>I had to rebuild my wooden floor three times before I noticed my lava fall outside was to blame. (Since it's SMP with bukkit, WorldGuard solved this issue for me)</sup>

Comment: That explains why my nice brick and wood home once became a fireball during a neighbors visit...damn lava moat.

Comment: @JiminP: yeah, I was already wondering when Notch would make minecraft more realistic :p

Comment: This explains how the fire got there, but I still want to know how *stone* can catch fire.

Comment: @John I've observed similar strange behavior with stone, dirt, and other non-flammables seeming to catch fire. I believe this is actually your sign or (in more than one case I observed) the tree burning, not the stone itself -- the fire shows up on the block adjacent to the one actually on fire. You can see this yourself if you go up to a tall tree, and then light the *bottom* block of wood on fire -- the grass/dirt/whatever *next to* the tree will seem to be on fire.

Comment: Kromey: Fire is a block, that's all. The flame graphics appear on the block below, and flammable surfaces in other directions, only if those blocks are present — but the fire is still a full block, just like everything else in Minecraft.

Comment: @John: I think that's the mechanics of fire, the game first determines _if_ something would catch fire and _afterwards_ checks whether it actually is burnable. I don't know if it's a bug or intended behaviour since otherwise you could safely walk around a pool of lava without ever catching fire yourself... (since your character is not a block)

Comment: The answer is a common misconception, but fireballs are just fancy particles and have nothing to do with blocks catching on fire. Now and then, MineCraft **randomly** picks blocks within a certain distance from a lava block and sets them on fire if they fill certain conditions. The fireballs have nothing to do with this random selection.

Comment: @IQAndreas Actually I didn't observe this that long to distinguish between "visual" and "inflaming" fireballs. Interesting if true, but not really relevant since it doesn't change the result: After a while anything burn-able too close to lave _will_ burn

Answer (score 6):

Combining the inputs of Raven Dreamer, chands, Tobias Kienzler, Kromey, Kevin Y, and Kevin Reid, I have decided that:

1: I caught on fire because I was unlucky enough to be diagonally southwest of a lava block.

2: The lava underneath my sign is tunneling up to it.

3: But because of a bug (possibly because a sign isn't a solid block), the blocks around my sign have been catching fire instead.

Many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 5):

I think this happens when you have a wooden but non-flammable block sufficiently close to lava to catch on fire; the fire-block is supposed to be burning the sign, but it doesn't — perhaps because the sign isn't a fully opaque solid block.

I've noticed this happening with fences, so it's likely the same thing here.

Answer (score -2):

To test if my garbage can was producing the fire, I placed wood next to it. But suprize, suprize! A pice of wood on the floor above it caught on fire without the wood next to the garbage catching on fire. My garbage is a hitech pit in the ground with lava in it.